# Is there a adaptive junk mail control in the Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, spam-prevention, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have been using Thunderbird for several months, its "adaptive junk mail control" helped me avoid a lot of spam emails. But recently, I started using Outlook, but I can't find the similar setting. Does it exist in the Outlook or some add-ins?

Comment: MS Outlook doesn't provide a similar option. Not sure whether there is any add-in could be used for this.

Comment: @SteveFan I'm sorry to hear that, I'm facing lots of spam emails every day in different languages.